# Table does not enter in number of sections and in number of rows

Tags: iphone, xcode, tableview

I am using tableView but it does not enter in number of sections and number of rows in tableView here is the code

here is the code for number of sections and number of rows.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {


return 1;

}
```

Number of Rows in Sections Code

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

   {

NSLog(@"Cell is");


return 1;
}
```

Cell Values

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


}


       MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MultipleDetailViewsWithNavigatorAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;    

        PublishData *theCellData = [appDelegate.publishArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

       NSLog(@"Cell is");


        cell.textLabel.text =@"Test";




        return cell;
```

}

Comment: Most likely you didn't connect the delegate outlet (if you use UIBuilder). And about a source code: you better provide a header here, not the implementation: the mistake is either in header (perhaps in extension-block in source file) or in UIBuilder

Comment: Set data source and delegate pls

Comment: self.tableView.delegate = self; self.tableView.dataSource = self;

Comment: You should consider to accept an answer if any of then resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set datasource and delegate for the table view? I suspect not. Please set it in code or xib and check.

Answer (score 0):

How you are have added table view ?. if you have added using interface builder then set your datasoure for the tableview. If you have added pro-grammatically then set [tableview setDatasoucre:self];